# geolocation - Identifying country by IP address

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

I want to implement log browser,ip,user,timestamp, but I want to add country,and state. I was trying to add some parameters from 
http://api.ipinfodb.com/ , but it doesn't because I only need to add to my default function json country code , country and state from the api , but I cant add it . I have an json with 600+ rows I need to store depends on the ip country , state and region. 
controller

```
public function datatable(){
        $array = $this->sessions->datatable();
        $this->json($array);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($array as $rows){
            $user_agent = $this->getBrowser($rows['user_agent']);
            array_push($data, array(
                $user_agent['name'].' on '.$user_agent['platform'],
                $rows['ip_address'],
                date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$rows['timestamp']),
            ));
        }
        $this->json(array('data' => $data));
    }

    public function tests()
    {
        $ip = '200.92.39.106';
        $this->load->config('geolocation', true);
        $config = $this->config->config['geolocation'];
        $this->geolocation->initialize($config);
        $this->geolocation->set_ip_address($ip);

        $city = $this->geolocation->get_city();
        if($city === FALSE)
            echo $this->geolocation->get_error();
        else
            echo $city;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer https://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/. Here is an example below:

```
$chs = curl_init('https://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/'.$this->input->ip_address());
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$geolocation = curl_exec($chs);
$geolocation = json_decode($geolocation, true);

$state = $geolocation['region']['state'];
$country = $geolocation['country']['name'];
$country_code = $geolocation['country']['alpha-2']; //if you want 3 letters like USA, try alpha-3
```

Now, you can insert (or update) your data:

```
$data = [
  'state' => $state,
  'country' => $country,
  'country_code' => $country_code,
  'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
  'timestamp' => time(),
  'user_id' => $your_user_id_variable
];
$this->db->insert('your_table_name', $data);
```

That's all! If you want to see a sample output for https://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/, please add your (or another) IP address and paste it to your address bar. (e.g: https://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/46.102.103.10)